# Sqlite database InsertOrThrow line not executed giving FATAL EXCEPTION - Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, exception

This is my database method to insert data in it...
It was working fine and suddenly, out of nowhere it started giving **FATAL EXCEPTION**

```
public boolean insertReport(String name, String title, String date, String status) {

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("name", name);
            cv.put("elabel_title", title);
            cv.put("date", date);
            cv.put("status", status);

            db.insertOrThrow("savedreports", null, cv);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I debugged it using breakpoints,
All going good but after execution of `cv.put("status", status);` line it jumps directly to the `finally` block :/
Not executing the insertOrThrow...
What am i doing wrong???

Comment: post your error message from the log cat !! Without that all we can do is guess

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had the same issue and this is the simple solution in my perspective.

"status" column surely not exist in your database column, please just check.

Problem is on this line

```
cv.put("status", status);
```

Might be You did not add this "status" column into your database.
Because it don't find any status column so it jumps out.

Comment: This is not the problem. `ContentValues` doesn't know anything about databases.

Comment: @Salmaan Yes but it wouldn't fail here.

Comment: Yes @laalto it didn't failed there, it jumped out to the finally block and while executing db.endTransaction(); i.e. without db.insertOrThrow("savedreports", null, cv); and db.setTransactionSuccessful(); gave FATAL EXCEPTION